# Liquibase changeset by dbms type

Tags: postgresql, properties, h2, liquibase, changeset

How can I use the same change set with content for different databases?

```
   <changeSet author="azare (generated)" id="some-data>
        <insert tableName="some-table">
            <column name="id" valueNumeric="1"/>
if h2
            <column name="some-column" value="h2-val"/>
if postgresql
           <column name="some-column" value="postgresql-val"/>
        </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to solve this issue:

```
<property name="val" dbms="postgresql" value="postgresql-val"/>
<property name="val" dbms="h2" value="h2-val"/>

   <changeSet author="azare (generated)" id="some-data">
        <insert tableName="some-table">
            <column name="id" valueNumeric="1"/>
            <column name="some-column" value="${val}"/>
        </insert>
   </changeSet>
```